# Rspec test on method that yields control

Tags: ruby, testing, rspec, yield

I am currently writing rspec tests for already written code of a project.
The code I am trying to test is something like the following:

```
def foo (ip, user)
    #[...]
    result = ""
    Net::SSH.start(ip, user) do |session|
        result = session.exec!('some_command_in_linux')
    end
    #[...]
end
```

What I am trying to accomplish is effectively decouple the assignment of the result from the execution of the remote command via SSH assign a fake string to the result variable.

I have read about **yield matchers**, but have not succeeded in applying them to my scenario.

More specifically, I was thinking something like:

```
expect {|block| Net::SSH::start(ip, user, &block).to receive(ip, user, &block).and_return(sample_output)}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: inject the session and use a test-double to decouple the test

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't need the block to actually *run* - simply ignore it. It won't run, but it would be safely ignored:

```
expect(Net::SSH).to receive(:start).with(ip, user).and_return(sample_output)
```

If you *do* want the block to run, use `and_yield`:

```
session = double(:session).as_null_object
expect(Net::SSH).to receive(:start).with(ip, user).and_yield(session).and_return(sample_output)
```

If you want the `session` object to behave in a certain way, you can `expect` it to do stuff:

```
session = double(:session)
expect(Net::SSH).to receive(:start).with(ip, user).and_yield(session)
expect(session).to receive(:exec!).with('some_command_in_linux').and_return(sample_output)
```

Comment: Awesome! I guess I was lost in something much more complex, in terms of passing the block as an argument.

In which case should you actually pass the block as an argument to an expectation?

Comment: You can't pass a block as an expectation @steve